# Update an Android app GridView when new item added to the JSON

Tags: android, json, gridview

In my application, I am loading the content for a GridView using a remote JSON file. But that JSON update once in a month. So the user no need to connect Internet every time he/she loads the GridView. So what I have done is, stored the data in to a database for the first time GridView load and next time I'm filling the GridView using the database.

Now I have a problem. I want to send a notification or something like that, when a new item added to the JSON file. *With out using C2DM*, is there any other way I can achieve my target?

I thought something like a notification that we get when a new version of an application is available. If it is applicable, how can I do that?

Comment: Can I use JAVA **HttpHeaders** class in Android ? [link]
(http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.0.10-alpha/index.html?com/google/api/client/http/HttpHeaders.html)
I think it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to push data onto your app the other obvious way is to poll at regular time intervals. A service can do that in the background. Once the server replies positively you can display a notification.

Comment: Please see my comment and give any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite see how the HttpHeaders class will solve your problem. Can you be a bit more precise.

Comment: What I meant is that you could  have a service that will schedule an alarm to poll for data every N minutes (or days in your case). Every time the alarm rings a thread is spawned to do the networking work and (if needed) the database update along with the user notification.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a different approach for the same question. Here we don't need to use either Push Notification or C2DM. By using `HttpUrlConnection` class and `getLastModified()` method, we can achieve our target.

Logic is, we save the last updated time of the file in our `SharedPreferences` and next time we load the app, the `SharedPreferences` value and the last update date of the value is same, we can load the cache data or the data we have saved in our database. If those values different, then only we download the data from the server.